# Cambiar el nombre de la red Wifi desde JavaScript

Tags: javascript, router

Resulta que quiero cambiar el nombre de mi Wifi, me compré un router, específicamente el DIR-608, básicamente todo el sitio web interno de la configuraciones está en JavaScript, y quiero ponerle un emoticon, al nombre del Wifi pero no me deja hacerlo, traté de cambiar valores en la consola, etc., pero no lo logré.

Según vi, esta es la parte donde valida que no existan otros caracteres especiales:

```
function checkSpecialChar(str,type)
{
    var patrn;
    if(type)
        patrn=/^[ a-zA-Z0-9~`!"@#$%^&*()_+|\\{}[\]<>:;<?,-./='"]+$/; 
    else
        patrn=/^[ a-zA-Z0-9~`!"@#$%^&*()_+|\\{}[\]<>:;<?,-./='"]*$/;
```

Ese es un archivo aparte que forma parte del HTML.

Aquí está la parte donde verifica que no existan caracteres especiales, esta está en la parte del formulario donde se introduce el SSID:

```
if(!checkSpecialChar(document.wlanBasicSetup.ssid.value,1)){
    alert('SSID no válido. Algunos caracteres especiales  no están permitidos');
    document.wlanBasicSetup.ssid.focus();
    return false;
}
```

El nombre del Wifi que me gustaría poner seria algo así: ✌, o al menos que sea texto normal con este emoji al final del nombre (✌).

---

cambie valores en la peticion, y logré cambiar el nombre al Wifi, pero no muestra los iconos/emoticons, debe ser por que no es un router de ultima generacion

Comment: Puedes saltar directamente la validación poniendo `if(true)` pero probablemente esa validación esté porque los caracteres pueden entrar en conflicto con otra parte del código, prueba y compártelo.

Comment: Lo ideal sería que busques algun get, ajax o post y a que archivo así puedes saltear todas las validaciones del cliente y vas directamente al que cambia el ssid.